# Migrating Symfony1.4 to Symfony 2.2 - What to reuse and how

Tags: symfony, symfony1, migration

I am about to migrate an old Symfony 1.4 Application to Symfony 2.2. I think this should be at least a bit planed. So I have several Questions, maybe you can help me:

- Is there maybe a good Tutorial out there (I didn't found one)
- Is it possible to reuse my old schema.yml and fixtures?
- I know about `doctrine:mapping:import` but I think this is not a good idea. Do you have good experiences with this command?

It's not very important to migrate the old data, because the App went inactive and could be started from scratch. However I am hoping to save some time in creation. So it's more about functionality migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions in turn :

> Is there maybe a good Tutorial out there (I didn't found one)

There is no documentation on migrating between versions as its not really possible - the 2 frameworks are very very different - i suggest you almost need to start again. [Read this on the differences between the 2 versions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/symfony1.html)

> Is it possible to reuse my old schema.yml and fixtures?

You can import your database structure - but not from schema.yml - direct from the database. You cannot reuse your old fixtures - [fixtures are still available though](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)

> I know about doctrine:mapping:import but I think this is not a good idea. Do you have good experiences with this command?

Its worked fine for me when I migrated my application from 1.4 to 2.1/2.2 - everything was picked up objects, properties and relationships - i recommend using it

I would say however that the documentation for Symfony (both 1.4 and 2) is excellent - the books and cookbooks are very well written and easy to read.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experiences. Maybe I should try `doctrine:mapping:import`.

Comment: I tried `doctrine:mapping:import` and it got 100% of my old Database schema. I can't believe it. Simple perfect. Thank you for the tip.